# Sharing TypeScript using Nuget

Tags: c#, typescript, asp.net-core, nuget, visual-studio-2019

It's a bit frustrating trying to make TypeScript shareable using Nuget packages. Imagine you have some common ASP.NET Core and TypeScript code that you would like to re-use in your organization or make available to the world. The most intuitive way would be to build your project as you normally would, and `GeneratePackageOnBuild` to create the Nuget package. However, regardless of what I tried with `tsconfig.json`, Nuget package manifest, changing the project file of the consumer project, I could not get it to work correctly.

By default, it only includes the JS files in the package, not the TS ones. This precludes any sort of auto-complete. Then I tried creating a custom package using Nuget Package Explorer (thinking once I get it to work, I can automate the creation as a follow up step). I manually added the TS files to the package as content. However it then started giving a whole bunch of errors, some times it treats `.ts` files as C#, other times it treats the `tsconfig.json` as C#. The absolute best I could accomplish was: the project built, after I tweaked the local TS files and the local `.csproj` file to reference the package local cache folder (yikes!!), and resulting JS files were output to `wwwroot` folder. But, they were in multiple sub-directories (including `users/myname/.nuget/packages/<<name>>/<<version>>/contentFiles/etc.` which is absolutely terrible) - I would need to add all those paths as `<script>` tags in my HTML.

If anybody knows how to do this, your help would be greatly appreciated.